# a solution to lonely runner conjecture for k runners

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math

I was trying to solve this problem in the last monthes and i think i found a solution for it for any k runners.
my question is: where can i submit my solution so it can be proved, should it be in a world math journal for example?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. That question is off-topic here.

Comment: As you may know, journals constantly receive claims that some major open problem or other has been solved.  As such, it can be hard to be taken seriously.  I suggest first trying to persuade some mathematician(s) in a relevant field.  In any event, this is not a good question for this site.

Comment: Thank you sir, i was really excited to be guided on how i can publish it.